# Spring Getting Started Guide MongoDB REST Example

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, rest, spring-boot

I looked at the MongoDB REST Getting started guide from Spring (https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-mongodb-data-rest/). When I'm adding an entity in a different package then the `Application.java`, say

```
com.project.rest.core.entities.Account.java
```

and do the same for the repository

```
com.project.rest.core.repositories.AccountRepo.java
```

the Application does not recognize the REST endpoints under localhost:8080 after building with. It just shows

```
{
    "_links": {
        "people": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/people{?page,size,sort}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "profile": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/profile"
        }
    }
}
```

When I put the `Account.java` and `AccountRepo.java` in the same package where the `Application.java` resides, it works.

So, how do I integrate Repositories from different packages in the Application?

Best regards,

Tim

EDIT: My main application class looks as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Even with added @ComponentScan(basePackages="com.project.rest") the AccountRepository is not found by Spring boot.

The repository has the following annotation:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "accounts", path="accounts")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the `Component`s and `Repositories` under any of the sub-packages as `Application.java`.

From [Spring Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-locating-the-main-class)

> We generally recommend that you locate your main application class in a root package above other classes. The @EnableAutoConfiguration annotation is often placed on your main class, and it implicitly defines a base “search package” for certain items.

Comment: Yes, I tried exactly that and now it works. Thank you very much Kapil!

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot should handle it with auto configuration annotation `SpringBootApplication`or `EnableAutoConfiguration`.

Also you can specify annotation `ComponentScan` scanning by adding additional annotation to the main application class.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.project")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Anton. Even with added @ComponentScan(basePackages="com.project.rest") the AccountRepo is not found. I edited my question for additional information.